# How to display signature in macro used for sending mail from outlook?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

Currently I have created a macro which have some content as Body and after that I want to show default signature of outlook user .

I have two buttons in excel and two macro one for each.

.Display is I think responsible for signature display but when I am using it , Signature is not coming for first macro and in second fuction its coming but on

the top of the body also.
Please advise what to do.
Below are my macros:-

```
    Sub email()         
    Dim OlApp As Object
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim myNameSp As Object
     'Set myNameSp = CreateObject("Outlook.Namespace")
    Dim myInbox As Object
     'Set myInbox = CreateObject("Outlook.MAPIFolder")
    Dim myExplorer As Object
     'Set myExplorer = CreateObject("Outlook.Explore")
    Dim NewMail As Object
     'Set NewMail = CreateObject("Outlook.MailItem")
    Dim OutOpen As Boolean
    Dim nameList  As String
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim CCLISt As String
    Dim Result As Integer
    Dim ResultTo As Integer
    Dim ResultCC As Integer
    Dim CCLISTAppned As String


    'count last working row
    With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
   Dim i As Integer

     For i = 11 To lastRow 'use cells 7 to 39 in column "I" where names are stored
     If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = "Y" Then
      If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & i).Value <> "" Then
      ResultTo = InStr(nameList, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & i).Value)
       If (ResultTo = 0) Then
        nameList = nameList & ";" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & i).Value
        End If
       Result = InStr(CCLISt, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & i).Value)
       If (Result = 0) Then
        CCLISt = CCLISt & ";" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & i).Value
        End If
         ResultCC = InStr(CCLISTAppned, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N" & i).Value)
       If (ResultCC = 0) Then
        CCLISTAppned = CCLISTAppned & ";" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N" & i).Value
        End If

        End If
    End If

      Next
      CCLISt = CCLISt & CCLISTAppned
        ' Check to see if there's an explorer window open
        ' If not then open up a new one
        OutOpen = True
        Set myExplorer = OlApp.ActiveExplorer
        If TypeName(myExplorer) = "Nothing" Then
            OutOpen = False
            Set myNameSp = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            'Set myInbox = myNameSp.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
           ' Set myExplorer = myInbox.GetExplorer
        End If

        ' If you  don't to display your outlook while sending email then comment the below statement
        'otherwise you can un-comment

        'myExplorer.Display

        ' Create a new mail message item.
        Set NewMail = OlApp.CreateItem(0)
        With NewMail
            '.Display ' You don't have to show the e-mail to send it
             .Display
            .Subject = "Audit Response Requested - ["
            .Subject = .Subject & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value & "/"
            .Subject = .Subject & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value & "]"

            .To = nameList
            .CC = CCLISt

            .HTMLBody = "<b><h2 style=color:blue; background-color:yellow><p style=background: yellow><center>Please use voting buttons above to facilitate your reply. </center></p></h2></b>"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "We have been asked by <b>" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value & "</b>, to furnish information in conjunction with their annual financial audit. "
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "According to the Firm's records, you have recorded time on matters for the Company [<b> [and/or its subsidiaries]</b> since their last annual audit. "
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "[<b> Our last letter (and its Exhibit A) is printed out below. </b>] Accordingly, please respond as to "
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "whether or not you have anything material to report. " & "<b>[Please send [email sender] if you have questions about any materiality thresholds.] [Our response is due [date]].</b>" & "  Thank you!"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><br>" & "For your information:" & "<br><br>"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Are you aware of any (1) pending litigation, or (2) overtly threatened litigation, meaning that a potential claimant has manifested to the Company an awareness of and present intention to assert a possible claim or assessment?"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "2.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Are you aware of or have you worked on any matter for the Company which may involve an unasserted possible claim or assessment that may call for financial statement disclosure? Financial statement disclosure of material unasserted claims or assessments may be required in the following cases:"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp(a)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;where there has been a manifestation by a potential claimant of an awareness of a possible claim or assessment and there is a reasonable possibility that the outcome will be unfavorable, or  "
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp(b)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;where there has been no manifestation by a potential claimant of an awareness of a possible claim or assessment but it is considered probable that a claim will be asserted and there is a reasonable possibility that the outcome will be unfavorable.  Examples of this include the following: "
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;(i) a catastrophe, accident, or other similar physical occurrence in which the client's involvement is open and notorious, or"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp(ii) an investigation by a government agency where enforcement proceedings have been instituted or where the likelihood that they will not be instituted is remote, under circumstances where assertion of one or more private claims for redress would normally be expected, or"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp(iii) a public disclosure by the client acknowledging (and thus focusing attention upon) the existence of one or more probable claims arising out of an event or circumstance"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "3.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Have you during the period in question called to the client's attention any matters you thought the client should consider for financial statement disclosure? <b/>"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "<b>[4.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Are you aware of any material litigation, claims or assessments relating to the Company that have been settled?]"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "<b>=============================<b/>" & "<br>" & "<b>Last [Annual] Audit Letter dated [***]<b/>"

        .VotingOptions = "NOTHING TO REPORT;Yes - Please choose edit to explain in email Reply;"

        End With

        'NewMail.Send
        'If Not OutOpen Then OlApp.Quit

        'Release memory.
        Set OlApp = Nothing
        Set myNameSp = Nothing
        Set myInbox = Nothing
        Set myExplorer = Nothing
        Set NewMail = Nothing


End Sub


Sub Reminder()

   Dim OlApp As Object
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Dim myNameSp As Object
     'Set myNameSp = CreateObject("Outlook.Namespace")
    Dim myInbox As Object
     'Set myInbox = CreateObject("Outlook.MAPIFolder")
    Dim myExplorer As Object
     'Set myExplorer = CreateObject("Outlook.Explore")
    Dim NewMail As Object
     'Set NewMail = CreateObject("Outlook.MailItem")
    Dim OutOpen As Boolean
    Dim nameList  As String
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim CCLISt As String
    Dim Result As Integer
    Dim ResultTo As Integer
    Dim ResultCC As Integer
    Dim CCLISTAppned As String



    'count last working row
    With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
   Dim i As Integer
     For i = 11 To lastRow 'use cells 7 to 39 in column "I" where names are stored
     If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = "" And Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = "Y" Then
      If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & i).Value <> "" Then
      ResultTo = InStr(nameList, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & i).Value)
       If (ResultTo = 0) Then
        nameList = nameList & ";" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & i).Value
        End If
       Result = InStr(CCLISt, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & i).Value)
       If (Result = 0) Then
        CCLISt = CCLISt & ";" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & i).Value
        End If
         ResultCC = InStr(CCLISTAppned, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N" & i).Value)
       If (ResultCC = 0) Then
        CCLISTAppned = CCLISTAppned & ";" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N" & i).Value
        End If

        End If
    End If

      Next
      CCLISt = CCLISt & CCLISTAppned
        ' Check to see if there's an explorer window open
        ' If not then open up a new one
        OutOpen = True
        Set myExplorer = OlApp.ActiveExplorer
        If TypeName(myExplorer) = "Nothing" Then
            OutOpen = False
            Set myNameSp = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
           ' Set myInbox = myNameSp.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
            'Set myExplorer = myInbox.GetExplorer
        End If

        ' If you  don't to display your outlook while sending email then comment the below statement
        'otherwise you can un-comment

        'myExplorer.Display

        ' Create a new mail message item.
        Set NewMail = OlApp.CreateItem(0)
        With NewMail
            '.Display ' You don't have to show the e-mail to send it

            .Subject = "Audit Response Requested - ["
            .Subject = .Subject & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value & "/"
            .Subject = .Subject & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value & "]"

            .To = nameList
            .CC = CCLISt
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "This is a quick reminder that our response for " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value & " is due. Please respond to below as soon as you are able. Thanks!"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<b><h2 style=color:blue background: #FFFF00><p style=background: yellow><center>Please use voting buttons above to facilitate your reply. </center></p></h2></b>"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "We have been asked by <b>" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value & "</b>, to furnish information in conjunction with their annual financial audit. "
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "According to the Firm's records, you have recorded time on matters for the Company [<b> [and/or its subsidiaries]</b> since their last annual audit. "
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "[<b> Our last letter (and its Exhibit A) is printed out below. </b>] Accordingly, please respond as to "
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "whether or not you have anything material to report. " & "<b>[Please send [email sender] if you have questions about any materiality thresholds.] [Our response is due [date]].</b>" & "Thank you!"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><br>" & "For your information:" & "<br><br>"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Are you aware of any (1) pending litigation, or (2) overtly threatened litigation, meaning that a potential claimant has manifested to the Company an awareness of and present intention to assert a possible claim or assessment?"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "2.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Are you aware of or have you worked on any matter for the Company which may involve an unasserted possible claim or assessment that may call for financial statement disclosure? Financial statement disclosure of material unasserted claims or assessments may be required in the following cases:"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp(a)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;where there has been a manifestation by a potential claimant of an awareness of a possible claim or assessment and there is a reasonable possibility that the outcome will be unfavorable, or  "
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp(b)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;where there has been no manifestation by a potential claimant of an awareness of a possible claim or assessment but it is considered probable that a claim will be asserted and there is a reasonable possibility that the outcome will be unfavorable.  Examples of this include the following: "
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp&nbsp;(i) a catastrophe, accident, or other similar physical occurrence in which the client's involvement is open and notorious, or"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp(ii) an investigation by a government agency where enforcement proceedings have been instituted or where the likelihood that they will not be instituted is remote, under circumstances where assertion of one or more private claims for redress would normally be expected, or"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp(iii) a public disclosure by the client acknowledging (and thus focusing attention upon) the existence of one or more probable claims arising out of an event or circumstance"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "3.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Have you during the period in question called to the client's attention any matters you thought the client should consider for financial statement disclosure? <b/>"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "<b>[4.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Are you aware of any material litigation, claims or assessments relating to the Company that have been settled?]"
            .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br>" & "<b>=============================<b/>" & "<br>" & "<b>Last [Annual] Audit Letter dated [***]<b/>"
             .Display
        .VotingOptions = "NOTHING TO REPORT;Yes - Please choose edit to explain in email Reply;"

        End With

        'NewMail.Send
        'If Not OutOpen Then OlApp.Quit

        'Release memory.
        Set OlApp = Nothing
        Set myNameSp = Nothing
        Set myInbox = Nothing
        Set myExplorer = Nothing
        Set NewMail = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anythyng for signatures. But you can edit the message body at runtime using VBA macros.

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) -  a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the HTML body of the specified item.
3. [Word editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) - the Microsoft Word Document Object Model of the message being displayed. The WordEditor property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which you can use to set up the message body.

You can read more about all these ways in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It us up to you which way is to choose to customize the signature in the message body.

Be aware, when you work with the `HTMLBody` property you need to add the signature content (a well formed HTML markup) before the closing `</body>` tag, not just append the HTMLBody string. So, find the closing body tag in the HTMLBody string and insert your signature there.

Comment: Its coming on bottom and top as well I need it on bottom only

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line next to `Set NewMail = OlApp.CreateItem(0)`

```
' Create a new mail message item.
Dim Signature As String
Set NewMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
Signature = NewMail.HTMLBody
With NewMail
    '.Display ' You don't have to show the e-mail to send it
     .Display
    .Subject = "Audit Response Requested - ["
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & vbNewLine & Signature
    .To = nameList
    .CC = CCLISt
```

Comment: Still m not getting signature in first macro and in second macro it is coming on top , problem remains same.

Comment: @KapilDhawan see update answer I have not tested yet

Comment: Its still coming on Top

Comment: When you work with the `HTMLBody` property you need to add the signature content (a well formed HTML markup) before the closing `</body>` tag, not just append the HTMLBody string. So, find the closing body tag in the HTMLBody string and insert your signature there.

Comment: With this it comes to bottom but also coming on top

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to get the signature with the method used in Omar's answer.

```
Sub email_Signature_Demo()

    ' Run this demo code in Outlook
    With CreateItem(0)

        MsgBox ".HTMLBody is not the signature." & vbCr & vbCr & .HTMLBody
        .Display ' This is required at the start, not the end
        MsgBox ".HTMLBody is the signature " & vbCr & vbCr & .HTMLBody

        .HTMLBody = "According to the Firm's records... " & .HTMLBody

    End With

End Sub
```